# Cartesian coordinate velocity and generalized coordinate velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, velocity, differentiation

use $x_k$ to denote the kth component of cartesian coordinate,  and $q_k$ to denote the generalized coordinate.

Taking the derivate of $x_k(q_1,q_2,q_3,t)$ w.r.t. time,  we have

$$\frac{d x_k(q_1,q_2,q_3, t)}{dt}=\sum_j \frac{\partial x_k(q_1,q_2,q_3,t)}{\partial q_j}\frac{d q_j}{d t} + \frac{\partial x_k(q_1,q_2,q_3,t)}{\partial t}.$$

What is an intuitive interpretation to $\frac{\partial x_k(q_1,q_2,q_3,t)}{\partial t}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates: the chapter on holonomic constraints gives more standard notation.

Comment: Think of a rotating coordinate frame. Then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = -\sin\theta$